# South manages a new app instead of syncdb

Tags: django, django-south

I've added a new app (specifically [tastypie](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html)) and tried to `syncdb` however [South](http://south.aeracode.org/) won't let me. I get:

```
Not synced (use migrations):
 - tastypie
```

Why would South insist on this while I didn't use `manage.py convert_to_south tastypie`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

South manages any app that has a /migrations folder under it.  Many 3rd party apps come with migrations built in, if you have south then those migrations are used if not then syncdb runs and you're good to go.

`convert_to_south` is a bit of a hack IMO.  It essentially runs generates the same thing as the command line `--init` would but also `--fake` it.  It doesn't really do anything all that "special".

Answer (score 2):

This is because tastypie has, for whatever reason, migrations.