# TastyPie Migration

Tags: django, migration, tastypie, django-south

I am getting the following error

After `python manage.py syncdb`

It says everything is synced, but then I see this

```
Not synced (use migrations):
 - tastypie
```

How do I sync `tastypie`?

I also have `South` synced. As apparently that makes a difference.

The following SO question referred to this problem but did not solve it or at least I did not understand the solution: [South manages a new app instead of syncdb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9367708/south-manages-a-new-app-instead-of-syncdb)

Can you please help me with this, thanks.

Keep in mind that this is my first time using Django

I saw another solution online but it required the app name and I put the app name down but it did not work (or maybe i don't know my app name). How do you find out the app name?

Comment: Feel free to comment if you would like any more info from me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
django-admin.py migrate tastypie
```